# Is there any way to change B2C properties post creation

Tags: powershell, graph, azure-authentication, azure-rest-api, azure-ad-b2c

I created one B2C tenant following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant

During creation, I entered details like Organization name as `Contoso b2c` by default.

Now I need to change these properties to different values. In normal AAD, I used to do that in `Properties` but unable to perform same in B2C tenant.

All tabs that I can see in B2C tenant under **Manage** are

- App registrations
- Applications (Legacy)
- Identity providers
- API connectors
- Company branding
- User attributes
- Users
- Roles and administrators

I cannot find Properties field in B2C tenant.

Is there any way to change B2C tenant properties from portal or rest api or powershell.

I tried checking most of the graph docs and found this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organization-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

But this doesn't satisfy my requirement. Any help?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below steps to change Azure AD B2C Organization Name.

Sign in to portal.azure.com with the Global Administrator account of the B2C tenant. Make sure you are connected to the B2C tenant and not the primary Azure AD tenant.

Navigate to Azure Active Directory > Properties, and under the Name textbox, use the new organization name.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/649444/azure-ad-b2c-change-organization-name.html